# Regex номер телефона, без лишних символов и начинается с +

Tags: регулярные-выражения, angular2

Я не специалист в regex, искал в тырнетах много разных вариантов, но находил только те, где есть символ со скобкой, пробелами и можно без символа +, это не подходит.

Нужен такой, чтобы можно было ввести только что-то на подобие вот этого

**+73495555555**

Без городских телефонов и т.д.

Без пробелов, скобок и **-**

Допустимые символы только **+** в начале и **цифры**. Если я правильно понимаю, то цифр не меньше 10, но не больше 13

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если кому нужно, то вот "^\+7\d{10,13}"